# how does env.BUILD_URL in jenkins running inside Docker container get the outside network port number correctly?

Tags: jenkins, docker, port, jenkins-pipeline

Trying out jenkins from official docker image of jenkins

```
docker run -d -p 8090:8080 jenkins
```

Note that I have chosen my host's `8090` port to map to the docker container's `8080` port.

Now, inside jenkins, i am running a sample pipeline where I have only one line

```
echo "${env.BUILD_URL}"
```

As a result of this pipeline script, the pipeline console output shows the following

```
http://localhost:8090/job/sample_pipeline/1/
```

Notice the port number `8090`?

My question is,

***How does jenkins from inside the container know that i have set 8090 as the host port that should map to the jenkins container's 8080 port?***

I mean, with `env.BUILD_URL` being invoked from inside the docker container, isn't jenkins supposed to look into its own host and return port `8080` as the port number where it is running?

Jenkins is not supposed to know that it's running as a container and that it needs to look outside its container scope to determine what is the external port number that it is mapped to?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `http://localhost:8090` to access the console and trigger the build I would guess that it picks it up from there.